# Prove $j:D\to \text{Hom}_R(S,S)$ is left $S$-module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, galois-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm studing the paper *Galois Theory and Galois Cohomology of Commutative Rings* by S. U. Chase, D. K. Harrison and Alex Rosenberg. I'm trying to read it carefully and understanding the definitions (which are a lot), and there's a moment in pages 3 and 4 where it's stated:

> "$S$ is a commutative ring, G is a finite group of ring automorphisms
> of $S$, and $R=S^G$, the subring of $S$ consisting of all elements of
> $S$ left fixed by every element of $G$. "
>
> "Let $D=D(S,G)$ denote the trivial crossed product of $S$ with $G$.
> This means that $D$ is a free $S$-module with generators $u_\sigma$
> ($\sigma$ in $G$), with $R$-algebra structure defined by the formula
> $$(su_\sigma)(tu_\tau)=s\sigma(t)u_{\sigma\tau}\phantom{a},\phantom{a}(s,t\in
>  S; \sigma,\tau\in G).$$ The identity of $D$ is $u_1$, and we shall
> denote it by the symbol $1$. There is an $R$-algebra homomorphism
> $j:D\to\text{Hom}_R(S,S)$ defined by $j(su_\sigma)(x)=s\sigma(x)$ for
> $s,x$ in $S$ and $\sigma$ in $G$. $j$ is also a left $S$-module
> homomorphism, where the $S$-module structure on $\text{Hom}_R(S,S)$
> arises from the $S$-module structure of the covariant argument. "

I've been trying to prove the statement "$j$ is also a left $S$-module homomorphism", but there is one point I'm not able to do and for the other I would like to check if they're correct.

**My work:**

1. **$D$ is left $S$-module:** I think this one's trivial by the definition of $D$.
2. **$\text{Hom}_R(S,S)$ is left $S$-module:** This is my main problem. The paper says it comes from the $S$-module structure of the covariant argument, but I'm unable to find what that is. So I tried proving it by hand, to be said, proving that $r,s\in S$, $f\in\text{Hom}_R(S,S)$ implies that $r(sf)=(rs)f$ and $(r+s)f=rf+sf$. I guess it must be trivial since $f(x)\in S$ $\forall x\in S$ and given that $S$ is a commutative ring then those properties must be verified (Correct me if I'm wrong). I'm probably wrong with this (I did not use the fact that $f$ is a left $R$-module homomorphism), so this is where my main question is (I'll ask it at the end again).
3. **Preserves module structures:** I didn't have problems here I think. It was pretty straight forward that
   $$j\left((su_\sigma)(tu_\tau)\right)=j(s\sigma(t)u_{\sigma\tau})=s\sigma(t)(\sigma\tau)=(s\sigma)(t\tau)=j(su_\sigma)j(tu\tau),$$
   $$j(rsu_\sigma)=rs\sigma=r(s\sigma)=rj(su_\sigma).$$

**My question:**

I think parts 1 and 3 of my proof are correct, but I would like confirmation of it. Part 2 is the problematic one, how can I prove $\text{Hom}_R(S,S)$ is left $S$-module? Is it trivial as I thought?

Any help or hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$
I will phrase things a bit more generally, and just consider $S$ as a ring extension of $R$.

As for 1., yes, the action on $D$ is $s.(s' u_\sigma)= (ss')u_\sigma$.

For 2, we have the following.
The $S$-action on $\Hom_R(S, S)$ being induced by the covariant argument means the following. For $f \in \Hom_R(S, S)$ and $s \in S$, we define $s.f$ as the endomorphism of the abelian group $S$ given by $(s.f)(x) = s f(x)$. (note that your equations $r(sf) = (rs)f$ etc don't make sense since you have not defined what the symbol $sf$ means.)

Now you have to show that $s.f$ is actually not just a morphism of abelian groups, but also intertwines the $R$-action. In terms of the inclusion $i \colon R \to S$, the relevant $R$-action on $S$ is of course given by $r.s = i(r)s$.
Then $(s.f)(r.x) = sf(i(r)x) = s i(r) f(x) = i(r) s f(x) = r. ((s.f)(x))$, where both the fact that $f$ is in $\Hom_R(S, S)$ and that $i(R)$ is in the center of $S$ were used.

This establishes $s.f \in \Hom_R(S,S)$.

And for the last point, you are almost correct, but you have to show that actually the functions $j((s u_\sigma) (t u_\tau))$ and $j(s u_\sigma) \circ j(t u_\tau)$ as well as $j(s s' u_\sigma)$ and $s . j(s' u_\sigma)$ agree, and I feel you have not really done that, because you have not actually compared the functions.
Instead, to be 100% precise, the computation should probably look something like
\begin{align}
j((s u_\sigma) (t u_\tau)) (x)
&= j( s \sigma(t) u_{\sigma \tau}) (x)
= s \sigma(t) \sigma (\tau (x))
= s \sigma ( t \tau (x))
\\
&= j(s u_\sigma) ( t \tau(x))
= j(s u_\sigma) \circ j(t u_\tau)(x)
\end{align}

This might seem like a nitpicky distinction, but it's not.